# Moving div above another using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html

I've seen a lot about doing this in CSS (far from ideal), but I'm thinking of building a Chrome extension and it requires that a div is inserted prior to another (for clarification, I mean that when testing the extension I need to drag the div above the other using Chrome Dev Tools). Is there a way to do this upon page load using Javascript/JQuery (or some other way which can be done via Chrome Extension)?

In previous attempts I've tried using `insertAfter()`/`insertBefore()` and `before()` and had no luck (although I might be missing something obvious), so I guess another question is do these need to be used in a certain way within a Chrome Extension?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/GmZ5V/) is a little demonstration.

The `insertBefore` code being used is this:

```
$("<div>").prop("id","between").insertBefore("#blah");
```

The first two jQuery functions just create the `div` element. If you want to move an existing one:

```
$("#existingDiv").insertBefore("#otherDiv");
```

And this should be pretty self-explanatory.

For plugins, load jQuery asynchronously. Something like this should do:

```
(function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( s );
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a very easy method to move one node before another, which you touched upon in your question:

BEFORE:

`<div id="first"></div> <div id="second"></div>`

```
$("#second").insertBefore("#first");
```

AFTER:

`<div id="second"></div> <div id="first"></div>`

---

As far as Chrome, you may want to do some digging to see if jQuery is loaded by the time you make your call or not

Comment: I guess that means the issues I'm facing must be with how it's being handled by Chrome then. I figured the JQuery should work fine, but you never know!